# Align btn-block buttons with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've since yesterday a bootstrap bug that I don't understand.
I put 2 buttons in a div with a flex display and an align-items-center but the second one is lower than the first one and I can't make the adjustment to correct it.

My code:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mt-1">
     <a href="/product/{{ $product->id }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"><i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down"></i></a>
     <a href="/product/{{ $product->id }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block ml-1"><i class="fas fa-store"></i></a>
</div>
```

My result:

[image: My bug]

Comment: You can use `mt-auto` aside `ml-1` or for both buttom. `m-1` for every button would be okay too ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap is designed so that consecutive `btn-block`'s stack vertically which is not happening because of the flex container. Instead of using `btn-block` inside the flex parent, use `flex-grow-1`...

```
 <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mt-1">
        <a href="/product/{{ $product->id }}" class="btn btn-primary flex-grow-1"><i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down"></i></a>
        <a href="/product/{{ $product->id }}" class="btn btn-primary flex-grow-1 ml-1"><i class="fas fa-store"></i></a>
 </div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/gtjiTMOt76

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the class .btn-block. As per bootstrap's documentation:
*Create block level buttons—those that span the full width of a parent—by adding .btn-block.*

And to space out multiple block buttons vertically, _buttons.scss in bootstrap has:

```
.btn-block+.btn-block {
    margin-top: .5rem;
}
```

So in your code, margin top is getting applied to the second button's **btn-block** class.

```
<a href="/product/{{ $product->id }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block ml-1"><i class="fas fa-store"></i></a>
```

You can either add below style to second button or modify class names depending on your requirement.

```
margin-top: 0;
```